# What is the name for the dagger that the protagonists of Cyber City Oedo 808 are wielding?

Tags: cyber-city-oedo-808

Does this weapon have a name? What is it?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dagger they are wielding closely resembles a [Jitte](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jitte), which is the Japanese equivalent to a [Sai](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sai_(weapon)) dagger

[image: Jitte with scabbard]